# Is content teasing effective?

Tags: interaction-design, design-patterns, text, conversion, hidden

so lately I've been wondering, if there's any research on efficiency of content teasers, and by that I mean blurred content (for example: answers to questions) with registration button. My main concern here is credibility - will the users belive there's actual content underneath the blur, will they see enough value in this, that they will register?

Comment: Is it effective as opposed to what? Just showing all the content itself?

Comment: Yeah, more or less. Will there be more users who register because there is value to the site itself (if there is, that is) or because we 'lured' them. But more importantly, how to create those teasers so they don't lower the users trust. I don't want them to think we just want their personal info and eventually they will get nothing. Im looking for a way to assure them they will get what they came for.

Comment: Why do you need them to register anyway? Sites like this very site you're on doesn't require registration to visit and we get quite a high number of visitors as a result.

Comment: well, I must say this is an odd question. Registrations are one of the most important KPIs for the company - this is strictly related to the business model.

Comment: It might be one of the most important KPIs for the company you refer to - but you've not explained that. Many, many sites happily (and profitably) exist without the need for people to register and give over their details. You can use Google without registering. You can use Reddit without registering. You can even use sites like eBay and hotels.com without registering, up until the point you *need* to provide details in order to receive the product. I don't think asking why you need registration is an odd question at all.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go ahead and suggest diminishing returns may be a reason not to force people to register.

Unless there is an underlying monetary business model that you cannot get away from, and even if that is the case there are reasons for loss leading, say an answer forum, giving away the first answer and blurring subsequent searches.

Back to the original question, I think a nicer user experience, notwithstanding what was said in the above paragraph, is to show users the content and gently coerce them into giving you their details.

You've already achieved part of your aim in driving the traffic to your site. A word of caution, sites that plonk registration forms in modal boxes on top of a web page can have a detrimental effect on registrations. Subtly providing the means to register on the same page and keeping the initial details to a minimum could work wonders.

Answered without knowing what you are teasing your users with!

[image: Example tease registration]