# How show content that is locked to unregistered users

Tags: registration, html, ux-designer, best-practice

I have a website with a block of text available only for registers users. The structure is something like this:

```
-Title available for all users
-Text available only for registered users and panel alert to notify unregistered users
```

Here is a screenshot of what I have now:

[image]

I am not sure if this way of show locked content is good, or just the panel alert is enough. Any study or opinion about this subject?

Answer (score 3):

I think there is possible another approach (a friendlier one, actually).

For the unregistered user you can show the title and a short excerpt (let's say, a 3-lines paragraph), followed by a Call2action/button prompting them to register: "Register to read entire article", "Full article available for registered users", etc.

This way you will accomplish a few more things: (1) teasing a bit the reader, giving a flavour of the reading, and (2) creating content blocks that are easily indexable by search robots.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for a panel alert to notify unregistered users to understand they need to register to view certain information.

Depending upon login, the system should understand if the user is registered or not.

Registered users get to see the title and content, while the unregistered users get to see only the title and a note next to that saying, they cannot view the information as they have not registered yet.

Showing blurred content makes no sense as it occupies space and is no way useful for the user.

Providing a "Register" Link next to that encourages the user to quickly register and get access to the information.

Something like what i have shown below.

[image]

Comment: about Showing blurred content, glassdoor for example, use something like my example for unregistered users when you try to read a review.  http://i.imgur.com/9kSBWnS.png

Answer (score 0):

**Let's be frank about this:** 
Your goal is to get users to get sign up.

This means you want them to be aware of your valuable content and to see what's underneath the barrier, without completely hiding it.

**Content Teasing:**

You'll have to seduce them into wanting to view the entire article.
if you fully block the article, they won't have an additional motivator to Register.

Like samples from a book. You want to know what you're getting into before signing up. For example: Make the first paragraph readable and fade/hide the rest.
"Register for free to read the full article"

- Make sure you remember the article they were viewing
- Ensure signing up is easy, fast, perhaps something they can complete later

**This brings us to a different question:**
[Is content teasing even an effective way to force sign-ups](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/62109/is-content-teasing-effective)?

You're focussing on the execution, but you should possibly revisit your initial goal and motivation. it's never a good idea to restrict users in navigation or viewing content unless there are ulterior motives such as business cases.

Comment: I am not sure if it's never a good idea. For some reason many crowd-sourcing platforms use the "register to see more" like glassdoor or quora. What this means is that everyone wants to read but no one wants to contribute, what leads to a bad ratio of producers vs readers. Do you know any study or literature about this?

Comment: What you're saying is absolutely true, depending on the nature of your website/platform the approach will be different. 

Although I didn't find find targeted studies towards the specific scenario that you're mentioning, I did come across many recommendations on how to make the locked content appealing using teasing.